# How can I rename a file with Ruby that includes a / character?

Tags: ruby, file, special-characters, rename

I've written a little Ruby command line app that I use to keep TV Shows organized on my Mac harddrive. Given the nature of TV episode titles there are episodes which include the `/` character.

Being on a Mac, the filesystem actually allows me writing this file and if I manually rename the file with the `/` character in it everything is fine.

The moment Ruby's `File.rename` runs in my script however I simply get a `No such file or directory` error because Ruby tries to read the `/` in the filename as a folder which should exist.

Here is an example:

Output path is `/TV/Showname/Season 1/Showname - 1x07 - 5/1.mp4`

Now rather than looking for the folder `/Showname - 1x07 - 5/` and write to a `1.mp4` file inside of it, how can I tell ruby to simply take the filename (`Showname - 1x07 - 5/1.mp4`) and write it into the `Season 1` folder as is?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A weird one this, but because the backslash is used as a file-separator, it is converted to a colon in the filename used by Ruby. So to rename your file, replace the forward slash in the name with a colon.

So you would write something like:

```
File.rename("Showname - 1x07 - 5:1.mp4", "/TV/Showname/Season 1/Showname - 1x07 - 5:1.mp4")
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot for the answer, tried it out by running `gsub( /\/|\\/, ':' )` over the episode title and everything works now.

Comment: By the way - you can alleviate some of your [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) by using `%r`. Calling `gsub(%r{/|\\}, ':')` is equivalent to `gsub(/\/|\\/, ':')`.

Comment: As far as I can see you only need to convert the forward slashes, so `gsub('/', ':')` should do it!